# How to assign values inside list using enumerate list comprehension?

Tags: python

```
# Setup
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Guest:
    name: str
    seat_no: str = None
ps_list = [(Guest('Ben'),'B1'), (Guest('Jerry'), 'B2')]

# Solution
new_lst1 = []
for i, j in enumerate(ps_list):
    j[0].seat_no = j[1]
    new_lst1.append(j[0])

print(new_lst1)
# Output
[Guest(name='Ben', seat_no='B1'), Guest(name='Jerry', seat_no='B2')]
```

How can I optimize the above code using list comprehension?

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**
`[Guest(name='Ben', seat_no='B1'), Guest(name='Jerry', seat_no='B2')]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple and fast list comprehension (don't use `enumerate` if you're not using the indices):

```
new_lst1 = [g for g, g.seat_no in ps_list]
```

Full demo ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pY6xasQwDIZ3P4XgBtsQjqZdykGhZCkU2qVTCSaYni51SGRjy5Q8fZrkcr2h3apBSL/0S18Y@dPT3X2I07SDN@QcxCn6AY6W7UdvU8IEbgg@8lUSj9dyzfCUMfFBwBxkBzxA4rh2CS035FcBHuDVE4qQmt4lnttarUYlKySpC1mVc4aL@Iwxjosgq1upjRA7ePc5QvJ9ZudJEH41feJyuWTEyUdwBXTgCJDygNEyqu2ZPsN19Y3Zb0yzq6tLc4beLu1tCEhHtexpIUJ0xOoy1P8hfxn/5m5h4W4LaH@4Zv7tkfmFME3f)):

```
# Setup
from dataclasses import dataclass
@dataclass
class Guest:
    name: str
    seat_no: str = None
ps_list = [(Guest('Ben'),'B1'), (Guest('Jerry'), 'B2')]

# Your solution
new_lst1 = []
for i, j in enumerate(ps_list):
    j[0].seat_no = j[1]
    new_lst1.append(j[0])

print(new_lst1)
ps_list = [(Guest('Ben'),'B1'), (Guest('Jerry'), 'B2')]

# My solution
new_lst1 = [g for g, g.seat_no in ps_list]

print(new_lst1)
```

Output (result from your code and mine):

```
[Guest(name='Ben', seat_no='B1'), Guest(name='Jerry', seat_no='B2')]
[Guest(name='Ben', seat_no='B1'), Guest(name='Jerry', seat_no='B2')]
```

Comment: exactly, I need this `new_lst1 = [g for g, g.seat_no in ps_list]`.Thank you.

Comment: The `[g for g, g.seat_no in ps_list]` is pretty clever. how did you do that? I actually didn't know that was possible in py code actually.

Comment: @rv.kvetch Yeah, I think it's a little-known and underused feature. I've rarely ever seen anybody else use it. Then again, most of the time you do want to assign just to bare variable names. So I'm happy every time I see a good opportunity to showcase this and make people aware that it's possible, and this particular example is just perfect for it. Not sure how to answer "how did you do that" other than with "I typed it with my fingers" :-)